# XML and PHP printing out specifics

Tags: php, xml

Im new to XML and decided I would try and use it to implement a simple CMS compared to constructing a whole MySQL database. However Im stuck on how to print things out on the webpage. In all tutorials I've seen they loop through each XML element and print out every one, I only want to print out the one where page name = home or page name = mypage.

This is simply done in MySQL with WHERE page["home"], but I cant find what the same code using XML is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content>
<page name = "home"><br />
    <title>Home</title><br />
    <subtitle>a test of my testing</subtitle><br />
    <top-papa>blah blah top para</top-papa><br />
    <mid-para>blah blah mid para</mid-para><br />
    <bot-para>blah blah bot para</bot-para><br />
    <image>
        <imge>mememem</imge><br />
    </image>
</page>
<page name = "whatdowedo"><br />
    <title>What do we do?</title><br />
    <subtitle>a test of my testing</subtitle><br />
    <top-papa>blah blah top para</top-papa><br />
    <mid-para>blah blah mid para</mid-para><br />
    <bot-para>blah blah bot para</bot-para><br />
    <image>
        <imge>mememem</imge><br />
    </image>
</page>
</content>
```

Many thanks to all replies.
Ben

Comment: thanks for the reply, i dont actually have anything on the webpage yet, just the xml file.

Comment: You query XML with XPath (XPath = SQL query on your XML). `/content/page[@name='home'][1]`. Show a bit of your code what you have so far, then it's easy to show where/how to place it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**XPath queries**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) on your XML document.

For example, if you have your XML in a string :

```
$str = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content>
...
</content>
XML;
```

And load it using [`simplexml_load_strin()`](http://www.php.net/simplexml_load_string) :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
```

You can then use the [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method to do an XPath query on that XML document -- searching, for example, by value of the `name` attribute :

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//page[@name="home"]');
if (count($nodes) > 0) {
    echo (string)$nodes[0]->title;
}
```

And, in this specific case, you'd get the following output :

```
Home
```

Note : the same kind of thing is, of course, possible with [**`DOMDocument`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), and [**`DOMXpath`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

Comment: thats great thanks. ive got this at current.
<? 
 $dom = simplexml_load_file("pages.xml");
?>

<? 
     $nodes = $dom->xpath('/content/page[@name="home"]');
if (count($nodes) > 0) {
    echo (string)$nodes[0]->title;
}

    ?>
and it prints it out perfect.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the XML of the page *home* like so:

```
Home:
<page name="home"><br/>
    <title>Home</title><br/>
    <subtitle>a test of my testing</subtitle><br/>
    <top-papa>blah blah top para</top-papa><br/>
    <mid-para>blah blah mid para</mid-para><br/>
    <bot-para>blah blah bot para</bot-para><br/>
    <image>
        <imge>mememem</imge><br/>
    </image>
</page>
```

you can do with the [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) quite quickly ([Demo](http://codepad.org/V6KGDfxD)):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
$name = 'home';
$xpath = sprintf("/content/page[@name='%s'][1]", $name);
$page = $xml->xpath($xpath);
if (!$page) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Page "%s" not found.', $name));
}
list($page) = $page;

echo $page->title, ":\n";
echo $page->asXML();
```